# Unable to load native libraries in android application

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, linphone

I am using a jar(linphone.jar) in my android application. This jar have a lib folder which have folders(armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86) contains .so files. I am getting error when i run my application. I have verified that libgnustl_shared.so file is in armeabi folder but still application crashing with a following error:

```
01-11 12:49:30.791 10484-10606/? E/ACRA: ACRA caught a UnsatisfiedLinkError for com.myapp.hp.testApp
                                     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.hp.testApp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.hp.testApp-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libgnustl_shared.so"
                                         at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
                                         at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
                                         at org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.<clinit>(LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.java:51)
                                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
                                         at org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreFactory.instance(LinphoneCoreFactory.java:47)
                                         at com.myapp.hp.testApp.sip.LinphoneManager.register(LinphoneManager.java:74)
                                         at com.myapp.hp.testApp.service.SipService.login(SipService.java:70)
                                         at com.myapp.hp.testApp.plugin.SipHandler$2.execute(SipHandler.java:83)
                                         at com.myapp.hp.testApp.plugin.SipHandler$2.execute(SipHandler.java:72)
                                         at com.myapp.hp.testApp.plugin.Executable$AbstractExecutable$1.run(Executable.java:36)
                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Can someone suggest how i can resolve this?

Comment: post your gradle as well

Answer (score 1):

Adding .so Library in Android Studio 1.0.2

1.Create Folder "jniLibs" inside "src/main/"
2.Put all your .so libraries inside "src/main/jniLibs" folder
3.Folder structure looks like,

|--app:

|--|--src:

|--|--|--main

|--|--|--|--jniLibs

|--|--|--|--|--armeabi

|--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files

|--|--|--|--|--x86

|--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files

No extra code requires just sync your project and run your application.

Reference 
https://github.com/commonsguy/sqlcipher-gradle/tree/master/src/main

Comment: Well i want to put all these native libs inside a jar rather than to make them as part of my android application(src/main/jnilibs). Is this possible to remain them inside the jar and resolve this issue?

Comment: You'll need to package them as aar file to do that.

Comment: This tutorial may help you didn't try

http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/04/start-working-on-linphone-android-part-1.html

http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/06/android-linphone-source-code-tutorial.html